# "is getting" vs "will get"

Tags: future-tense, present-continuous, future-time

Are there difference between those sentences?

> 1. Alex **is getting** married next month.
> 2. Alex **will get** married next month.

Seems that the first one is expressed in present continues, and the second on in future tense. Am I correct?

Comment: *Alex **gets** married next month* is equally valid. If you want to call that "present tense" you can, but ***next month*** clearly establishes that Alex's marriage lies in the future (it's not happening *now*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The present continuous/progressive construct can be used to refer to a future event, typically a near-future event, especially if qualified with a time expression.

> I'm going to the park tomorrow.
>
> I'm leaving this job in two weeks.
>
> She's testing the device next year.

There's little difference in meaning if a time expression is used.  If a time expression is not used or able to be pulled from context, it could be confused with an actual continuous or progressive meaning.

> John will get married. (We don't know when but we know he plans to get married.  He's not in the process of doing that now, though.)
>
> John is getting married. (He is either planning to get married or midway in the process of getting married.  This is ambiguous unless context provides information.)